# Razor output not working in MVC 3 but working in MVC 2

Tags: razor

This same code working fine with MVC 2 but not working in MVC 3 Razor. Once page is loaded not loading menu from HTMLHelper called within Razor like below.

Hardcoded menu for testing which is not outputting on the page.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using myproject.Extensions;

public static class MenuHelper
{

    public static string TabbedMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<MenuTab> tabs)
    {
       //I have hard coded menu for testing purpose.

        return "<div class='menu-image'><img src='/content/Images/common/on-left.gif' alt='' /></div><div class='on'><a class='over' href='/?Length=4'>Home</a></div><div class='menu-image'><img src='/content/Images/common/on-right.gif' alt='' /></div><a href='/Home/About'>About</a><a href='/Home/Contact'>Contact</a>";
    }

}
```

Below is Razor CSHTML code.

```
 @{Html.TabbedMenu
                        (
                            new List<MenuTab>
                            {
                                MenuTab.Create("Home", "Index", "Home"),
                                MenuTab.Create("About", "About", "Home"),
                                MenuTab.Create("Contact", "Contact", "Home")
                            }
                        );}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping code in `@{ ... }` (like you did) is Razor's equivalent to `<% ... %>` (without an `=`).

Therefore, your code calls the function, but doesn't do anything with the result.

You should remove the `{}` and the `;` and simply write `@Html.TabbedMenu(...)`; this is equivalent to `<%: Html.TabbedMenu(...) %>`.

You'll also need to change the method to return an `HtmlString` to prevent Razor from escaping the HTML.

Comment: Ok changed this as below
public static HtmlString TabbedMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<MenuTab> tabs)
{
 return new HtmlString("HTML MENU HERE AS ABOVE");
}

 @Html.TabbedMenu
(
 new List<MenuTab>
 {
  MenuTab.Create("Home", "Index", "Home"),

 }
)

Error is below
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult' c:\Path 19 myproject

Comment: @user: Remove the whitespace before the first `(` or wrap the entire call: `@(Html.TabbedMenu   (...)   )`  The Razor parser sees that whitespace and stops parsing.  (it thinks you're using a property)