# Output string from a function that is inside called inside @{}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The problem I'm having is simply returning a string when calling the following function:

```
@{StringUtil.IfNullorEmptyOutputHyphen<decimal>(ViewBag.StockItem.Height);}
```

Here the @{} is required because the argument might be null, and thus a type constraint is required .

```
@StringUtil.IfNullorEmptyOutputHyphen<decimal>(ViewBag.StockItem.Height)
```

The above gives an error because of

```
<decimal>
```

Thus calling the function inside @{} becomes necessary.

The function for completeness is:

```
public static IHtmlString IfNullorEmptyOutputHyphen<T>(T? value) where T : struct
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return new HtmlString("wtf99");
    }

    return new HtmlString(value.ToString());
}
```

To summarise, how can i return a 'string' from from a function that is called within @{}

Comment: don't call the function in the view. Your controller should call a function and populate a static field in a model. Separation of concerns, you've got logic in your model/View.

Comment: @Liam Good point... I'm working with legacy code and am currently looking at reworking a few things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap it in parenthesis:

```
@(StringUtil.IfNullorEmptyOutputHyphen<decimal>(ViewBag.StockItem.Height))
```

Comment: Lolz I typed my answer as you answered.... thanks anyway ;) I'll mark yours as the answer anyways, but can't for 10 mins for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
@(StringUtil.IfNullorEmptyOutputHyphen<decimal>(ViewBag.StockItem.Height))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gah nevermind, the solution is so simple I could kick myself:

```
@(StringUtil.IfNullorEmptyOutputHyphen<decimal>(ViewBag.StockItem.Height))
```

Use round brackets to encapsulate the function call instead.

Comment: Gleaned the answer from the last comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287827/razor-output-not-working-in-mvc-3-but-working-in-mvc-2